# linux popen stuck on fgets

Tags: linux, android-emulator, popen, fgets

guys! I use the popen function to execute shell script on linux(ubuntu16.04).

```
char buffer[1024];
char cmd[1024];
snprintf(cmd, 1024, "./vm_manager.sh start %s %d %d", vm_name, vm_start_port, vm_start_core);

FILE *fp = popen(cmd, "r");

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL){
    printf("%s", buffer);
    fflush(stdout);
}   
printf("over=============");
pclose(fp);
```

In vm_manager.sh, just run a android emulator cmd to start a avd like below:

```
emulator -avd $VM_NAME -kernel $KERNEL -port $VM_START_PORT -no-window -writable-system -ranchu -cores 4 -gpu mesa &
```

Actually it logs out the emulator start log, **but stuck on the fgets and never print out the "over===".**

Thx for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by add a end_flag in shell script:

```
echo "START_SUCCESS"
```

then in c++ check whether end_flag show up. if show up, just break the fgets loop:

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL){
    printf("%s", buffer);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(strcmp(buffer, "START_SUCCESS\n") == 0){ 
        break;
    }   
}
```

Thx anyway.